# looping data and push to a different array to prevent sent header error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hey guys i have this rest api that fetch data from my db to client side but since am looping each data to fetch and return the result through a res.json fromat, which actually works fine but am always having this error of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client and it makes the returning api malfunction. so i was wondering if its possible to create an empty array and then push data to it ouside the loop function and send the array through the res.json format to the client site to prevent the error. please if this is possible i need help on how.

my rest api code

```
Router.post('/getFeeds/forMe',authoriazation,async(req,res)=>{
  
    const getFeeds = []
    try {

//req.body.following is an array of users which we will loop through and get data of each of them!
         if (req.body.following.length > 0) {
            req.body.following.forEach(async (element,i) => {
         const GetFeed = await Feed.find({$or:[{feedType:'palsfeed',feedby: element.follow_to },{feedby: req.user}]}).sort({ date: -1 }).sort({ date: -1 })
          if (GetFeed) {
            if (GetFeed.length > 0) {
                //returns array to the client side
               res.json({feeds:GetFeed})
               

            }
          }
 
        });
        
     }else{
       const GetFeed = await Feed.find({feedby: req.user }).sort({ date: -1 })
       if (GetFeed) {
         if (GetFeed.length > 0) {
             //returns array to the client side
            // console.log({feeds:GetFeed})
         }
       }
     }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})
```

Comment: That means you most probably are sending a response to the client in your "authoriazation" middleware (misspelt in the code)

Comment: yea the authorization middleware holds the id of the user logged in

Comment: But does it have a `res.send` or `res.json` or `res.render` or anything sending a response?

Comment: if (GetFeed.length > 0) {
                //returns array to the client side
               res.json({feeds:GetFeed})
               

            } // this returns an array of data to the client using res.json

Comment: Remember that middlewares run in order; you can't send a response twice. Remove the `res.json` line from `authoriazation`.

Comment: there isn't any the else statement actually works fine since am not looping from anything am just fetching the data and sending it to the client but for the for the foreach loop it returns the error

Comment: In that case, I see that you might be sending the response more than once if `req.body.following` has at least two items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `loop` here. You are looping and sending the response. This way your API is sending multiple responses.

This problem can be resolved by modifying your query and not sending the response inside the loop.

So here we will use `$in` to solve the problem:

**Your modified code:**

Here, I am pushing `element.follow_to` into an array `follow_to_arr`. And then using `$in` query like `feedby: { $in: follow_to_arr }}`

```
if (req.body.following.length > 0) {
    const follow_to_arr = [];
    req.body.following.forEach(async (element,i) => {      
        follow_to_arr.push(element.follow_to);
    });
    
    const GetFeed = await Feed.find({$or:[{feedType:'palsfeed',feedby: { $in: follow_to_arr }},{feedby: req.user}]}).sort({ date: -1 }).sort({ date: -1 })
      if (GetFeed) {
        if (GetFeed.length > 0) {
            //returns array to the client side
           res.json({feeds:GetFeed})               
        }
      }
 }
```